# Doubts on dynamical systems concepts

Tags: dynamical-systems

I've been looking for explanations and examples of these concepts on internet, but I'm not finding anything that makes me truly understand this... The concepts are:

- fixed point vs periodic point
- periodic point vs periodic point of period $k$
- orbit vs periodic orbit
- periodic orbit vs periodic orbit of period $k$

I would be truly thankful if someone could give me some examples, so that I could truly understand these concepts

Comment: Why is this a topology question? Without further elaboration, this would seem to be a dynamics question.

Comment: I'm going to edit that, sorry @Thorgott